# Group and Filter Collection by another Collection in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a huge set of data in this form:

```
public class Permission
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string PermissionLevel { get; set; }
}
```

And a second collection as a `List<string> SiteCollections`. Sample data:

```
http://domain/project/1
http://domain/project/2
http://domain/project/3
http://domain/project/4
http://domain/project/5
```

Now my target is to filter this `List<Permission> Permissions` by `User`. So this gives me

```
var FilteredAndGrouped = data.Where(u => u.User == @"domain\username")
```

After this I want to group this result by part of its url. Every Permissions url is starts with one of the urls in the List SiteCollections.

If have started out with

```
var filteredAndGrouped = data.Where(d => d.User == @"domain\User")
                             .GroupBy (d => SiteCollections.Any (sc => sc.StartsWith(d.Url)))
```

This results in a grouping with the keys true/false and only the urls which are excatly as in the List `SiteCollections` are in the grouping with the key true. 
What I want is a grouping with the keys being the url in the list `SiteCollections` and the Permissions Url needs to start with the key of the grouping. It does not need to be equals to it.

In the end I need a result in this form:

```
Key: http://domain/project/1
    Permission 1 (Url: http://domain/project/1/xyz/xyz)
    Permission 3 (Url: http://domain/project/1/xyzz/xqeqyz)
    Permission 7 (Url: http://domain/project/1/xadadyz/xadadyz)
Key: http://domain/project/2
    Permission 2 (Url: http://domain/project/2/adyz/xdyz)
    Permission 4 (Url: http://domain/project/2/a2dyz/xdyz)
    Permission 21(Url: http://domain/project/2/a22dyz/xdyz)
Key: http://domain/project/3
    Permission 22 (Url: ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var groupped = permissions
    .GroupBy(x => SiteCollections.FirstOrDefault(u => x.Url.StartsWith(u)))
    .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Permissions = x.ToArray() })
    .ToArray();
```

Result may contain `null` key, that means that url doesn't exist in `SiteCollections`.

Comment: Note to myself: I am borderline stupid. I am curretnly staring at the `FirstOrDefault()` and think to myself: Why didn't I use it?
Works like a charm. Thank you a lot

Comment: Sometimes, *you can't see the wood for the trees* :)